# Ubuntu DVD doesn't boot

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu along-side Win7.

After burning the ISO an a DVD, I tried booting from DVD. Ubuntu says "remove media from tray, close tray and hit enter", which I do, but my laptop then immediately boots into Win7.

Comment: Your DVD isn't bootale. See this thread http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ht/burnisofile.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly common.  Do you have a UEFI bios or something newer?  If so, you will want to look at the ubuntu official guild on UEFI bios installs.  You may need to boot it from the live DVD and do a repair of the boot section.  Here is the guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI